# How to set php variables from other php variables like this?

Tags: php, variables

How to set php variables from other php variables like this ?

```
$aaa = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdadkjhasdkhasewrfsdjhslf";
```

i want to set `$bbb` = first char to twenty char of `$aaa` like this using function php

```
$bbb = "1234567890qwertyuiop";
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: did you try `substr` or `mb_substr`?

Comment: The `substr` function is a good place to start. Read the docs!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Use substr() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$bbb=substr($aaa,0,20);
```

You could have at least tried to google it. This function

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

> Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

**[substr manual and a number of examples](https://www.php.net/substr)**